# How to publish Image and IMU data from Android device?

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

First of all, i'm a newbie in ROS. I was going through the following tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/Publishing%20video%20and%20IMU%20data%20with%20roslibjs

I kind of understood what is going on in this program. But, i don't know how to run it. I would be grateful if someone lends me a hand to get through this problem.

Thanks in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250915/how-to-publish-image-and-imu-data-from-android-device-?/) by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not really "a program" (in the traditional sense), but a html page with an embedded javascript.

> But, i don't know how to run it.

You'd need to set up the `rosbridge_suite` infrastructure on the ROS side and then load the web page into a browser on the Android device. The Android device should be able to reach the `rosbridge` node (ie: be able to network with the ROS PC).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on 2016-12-29**:
Thanks for your reply. So, should i run "roscore" and "roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch" command  in my computer to receive the data from android device ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-29**:
`roscore` will be run automatically for you by `roslaunch` if you don't do it yourself, but basically: yes.

**Comment by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on 2016-12-29**:
i opened the html file in my Android Phone and opened the console in it. Then i ran "roscore" and "roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch" in my laptop. But, nothing happens.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-29**:
First: I think the order should be the other way around: first `roslaunch` `rosbridge`, then open the web page.
Second: the tutorial states:

> make it accessible via a webserver running on the server that is running the rosbridge [..]

Did you do that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-29**:
Also: what did you expect to happen? The JS only causes the phone to publish IMU and `sensor_msgs/Image` msgs. If you don't subscribe to those, you won't see anything.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-29**:
You can start a 'simple web server' on your ROS pc by running:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

in the directory containing the html file.